How to forward access to a port on one interface to another interface's port on the same machine?
Basically, I've got a service listening to eth0's 10.16.1.1 on port 1000 on a Ubuntu 22.04 machine. This service doesn't allow to listen to a catchall like 0.0.0.0 (outside of my control). This is an internal network.
For remote access, I've also got a VPN network running on wg0 which assigned the adress 192.168.100.1 to this machine.
Here's the question: How do I forward requests to 192.168.100.1:1000 to land at 10.16.1.1:1000?

You can use the iptables DNAT action to redirect traffic:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING \
  -d 192.168.100.1 \
  -p tcp --dport 1000 \
  -j DNAT --to-destination 10.16.1.1:1000

